# Class Not Updating when useing case in javascript

Tags: class, cookies, classname, getelementsbyclassname

I don't know why the class does not be udpated in following script using the (case):

```
 if (favorite !== null) {
     switch (favorite) {
         case 'cat':
             document.getElementById("one").className = "favBlue";

             //document.getElementById('one').className ='favRed';
             //document.createAttribute('class','favRed') 

             break;
         case 'dog':
             document.getElementsByName('dog').className = 'favBlue';
             break;
         case 'gerbil':
             document.getElementsByName('gerbil').className = 'favYellow';
             break;
         case 'gopher':
             document.getElementsByName('gopher').className = 'favWhite';
             break;
     }
 }
```

Please click on this link in order to see the complete script http://jsfiddle.net/gu8u6eoc/6/

Comment: Please complete the code in the fiddle :)

Comment: ok...I don't know why fiddle does not accept my code :(

Comment: what I am trying to do is to set a cookie that store the selections of the user then add a custom class in the specific <li>.

Comment: I believe you should just use `getElementById` then. where id is the specific <li>'s id attribute. Similar to what you did to `<li id="one">1</li>`

Comment: I did that with id="one" but getElementById does not in my case work as well.

Comment: it does. just be sure to Click 'Run' again in the fiddle. Also, every time a checkbox is clicked, you should run the `GetCookie()` function to update the list. See the updated fiddle link in my answer. :)

Comment: I appreciate your support. yes, now it is working fine. but unfortunatily after I refresh the page, the sitting is removed. in other word, the cookie is not saved... can you please help me :)

Comment: and what is the best way that if the user select more than one input then style of multiple <li>s is updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement is working. But I think you should use `document.getElementById(id)` instead of `document.getElementsByName(name)` to change the class values. Also, you are applying the classnames to the checkboxes which won't change their colors. You should apply the classnames to the texts instead.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), `getElementsByName` have different behavior per browser (e.g. sometimes it will work on elements with a similar `id` attribute to `name`). Also, `getElementsByName()` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array.3F) instead of an `Element` object.

BTW, here is a simplified working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/gu8u6eoc/13/). This contains both the usage of `getElementById` and `getElementsByName`.